# Using Emacs Tramp to ssh into dreamhost shared server

Tags: emacs, dreamhost

I can ssh in using openSSH and it takes me right to my home folder. But when I use TRAMP it is taking me to what seems to be a root directory (/boot, /bin, etc). I can't seem to get from there to my home folder. I don't know what to do. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For some reason, unlike other ssh clients I was using, it make me specify ~ as home server (rather than /)